# InsertOrUpdate vs. InsertOrMerge in Azure Storage Tables, what is the difference?

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

After looking at the Microsoft documentation for both of these methods, I don't see any difference between two, or maybe I've missed something.  I've experimented a little with InsertOrMerge, but all it does it replace the old data with the new data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685907/difference-between-insert-or-merge-entity-and-insert-or-replace-entity

Comment: That makes total sense now. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 9):

InsertOrUpdate = replaces the entire entity, including removing any fields that were not defined in the new entity.

InsertOrMerge = The old fields and values remain if the new entity does not include them, and all the other fields will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2011/09/15/windows-azure-tables-introducing-upsert-and-query-projection/

> The two Upsert APIs provided by Windows Azure Table are
>   InsertOrReplace Entity and InsertOrMerge Entity which are defined as
>   follows:
>
> - [InsertOrReplace Entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh452242.aspx): as the API name implies, InsertOrReplace Entity will insert the entity if the entity does not
>     exist, or if the entity exists, replace the existing one. This means
>     that once the operation successfully completes the table will contain
>     the new entity with properties as defined in the InsertOrReplace
>     Entity request, replacing the prior entity and its properties if it
>     had previously existed.
> - [InsertOrMerge Entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh452241.aspx): InsertOrMerge Entity will insert the entity if the entity does not exist or, if the entity exists, merges
>     the provided entity properties with the already existing ones. Once
>     the operation successfully completes, the table will contain the
>     provided entity with updated properties provided in the request. In
>     other words, if the entity exists, the API would have the same effect
>     as [Merge Entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179392.aspx), where the resultant entity is a union of
>     properties between the existing and the updated ones.

Comment: One important thing to point out here is that both for InsertOrReplace and InsertOrMerge, table service omits the Etag even if it is defined. So you may end up replacing or merging an older version of the entity. There is no version of these api s that consider Etag as far as I know which is a bit unfortunate.

Comment: @DoguArslan I think the API design is reasonable - if you know ETag value of the entity, you must already got the entity from Azure Table Storage service side, hence you should call Replace/Merge API rather than InsertOrReplace/InsertOrMerge API.

Comment: That's mostly correct for simple use cases but not always the case if you are working on globally distributed systems and eventual consistency. The table you read the entity from and the one you want to merge to may be different tables. I think it would be better if the api left the decision to clients to omit Etag via * as other non-insert versions.

Comment: 1. Actually, InsertOrMerge API shares the same HTTP verb and request Uri as Merge API. The only difference between them is if their requests contain HTTP header "If-Match" (for ETag). Therefore, if you specify ETag (either a real value or *), you're using Merge API already. 2. If you read an entity from one table and then merge it to other tables, you shouldn't assume the ETag functionality can still work across tables since the ETag is only designed for the same entity on the same table per API contract.

Comment: 1 is implementation detail ie. a custom header could be used to differ between Merge and InsertAndMerge and If-Match could be processed independently. Not clear on your second point we call InsertAnd.. Methods via the sdk. Though we implemented insertAndConditionalMerge Replace methods ourselves on the client side but would be better if service supported them natively. We may be going beyond the scope of the question so I may open a different topic here or a request in github.